# How can I return the nth regex match in a string?

Tags: regex, plsql

Working in PL/SQL.

I've got the following string

```
('Jade Court','Sarah M.', 4, '08/17/2017')
```

I need to write a regex that can parse each item in between the `'` characters.  So for example, I need `Jade Court`, `Sarah M.`, `08/17/2017` etc.

So far, I have come up with the following regex:

```
(?<=')[^']+(?=')
```

As you can see from the demo below, this works so far by finding each of the necessary items at the same time.

https://regex101.com/r/CV8evw/1

However, I need to be able to parse them out individually.  Is there a way to add a quantifier to my regex so that I can specify which match I want?

I tried `(?<=')[^']+(?='){1}` which I was hoping would return `Jade Court`, but unfortunately that did not work.  Is this possible?

Comment: Try `REGEXP_SUBSTR( col, '''([^'']+)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`, then, to extract the second one, `REGEXP_SUBSTR( col, '''([^'']+)''', 1, 2, NULL, 1)` and so on

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes it works!  Thanks for the suggestion!  The other answers below are also extremely helpful as well.

Comment: I posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409583/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this regex :

```
/\w{2,}\/?\s?\w*(\/\d{4})?/g
```

just visual test using `javascript`

```js
const x = "('Jade Court','Sarah M.', 4, '08/17/2017')"

const regex = /\w{2,}\/?\s?\w*(\/\d{4})?/g

console.log(x.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) and leverage its *nth_appearance* argument.

The regex you may use is

```
'([^']+)'
```

It matches `'`, then captures any 1+ chars other than `'` into Group 1 and then matches `'`. The Group 1 value can be accessed via *sub_expression* argument set to `1`. See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re='(%5B%5E'%5D%2B)'):

[image]

So, to get the first match, you need to use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '''([^'']+)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

To extract the second one, use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '''([^'']+)''', 1, 2, NULL, 1)
```

And so on.